# Vertical align issue inside a div

Tags: css, html

I am trying to vertical align middle for my input and a tag element inside a div.

I have

```
<div id='title-container'>
       <img id='logo' src='images/topLogo.png'>
       <div id='search'><input type='text'><a id='btn' href='#'>test button</a></div>
</div>
```

I want to display something like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    ---------------------------                             
|    |       topologic.png      |        my input box    test button                         
|    ---------------------------                        
|____________________________________________________________________
```

CSS

```
#title-container{ 
   height: 80px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background-color: yellow;
}

#search{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;   
}
```

I want to vertical align my `input box` and `test button` inside my `title-container` div and float these two items to the right.

I have tried adding

```
#search{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;   
   float:right;  
}
```

but those element will be on top of the title-container div instead of middle.. Can someone help me about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical-align property in CSS doesn't do what you'd expect. Typically, inline elements can be vertically aligned in their context via vertical-align: middle. But the context is the height of the text line they’re in, not the parent.

See http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

HTML:

```
<div id='title-container'>
    <div id='logo'><img src='http://placehold.it/60x40' /></div>
    <div id='search'>
       <input type='text' />
       <a id='btn' href='#'>test button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title-container{ 
   height: 80px;
}

#logo, #search {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 80px;
    float: right;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
}

#logo img {
    vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

[See the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/L967K/3/)

Comment: I need to have the logo image align to left. This would almost do the trick. +1 though.

Comment: NP. Updated the answer and the example link. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to play with `vertical-align`, you need to be aware that stuff like images have default `vertical-align` values set. This means, even though you set it to be `middle` for your parent container, it is being set as `text-bottom` on the image itself, by default.

You need to force it for all your elements inside that you want to act the same way:

http://jsfiddle.net/H9XBA/

```
#title-container img#logo, 
#title-container #search { vertical-align: middle; }
```

... and it will vertically align :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for logo's, I like wrapping them in a DIV and then adding an id to that DIV.

Another way you can vertically-align them to the middle is by using

```
display: table
```

for the parent div... and for the children that you want to align middle you put:

```
display: table-cell;
vertically-align: middle
```

You can check out an example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/QGg6P/