# Vertically align a floated element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align my ul tag and a tag inside a div

I have something like

```
 <div id='tabs-container'>
       <ul id='tabs'>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/homeBtn.png'</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>task</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>result</a></li>
       <li><a href='#'>Store</a></li>
       </ul>
       <a id='grade-btn' href='#'>checkout</a>
  </div>

----------------------------------------------------------
|
|   img task result store                       checkout      <- vertically align inside a div
|_________________________________________________________
```

I want something like above.

My css.

```
#tabs-container{      
    height: 65px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#tabs{
   float: left;
}

#tabs li{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#grade-btn{
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   float: right;
}
```

It doesn't really work. The checkout is not vertically aligned.

Comment: possible duplicate of your other 2 recent questions: [Vertical align issue inside a div with float element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152532/vertical-align-issue-inside-a-div-with-float-element) and [Vertical align issue inside a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134933/vertical-align-issue-inside-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to tabs-container `line-height: 65px;`

Comment: @FlyingCat I can try to explain, the btn is restricted by the font height of the container, making the line height the total height of the div allows it to move freely.

Comment: Line-height is divided in half and then applied to both the top and bottom of the element causing the element to be in the vertical middle. Adding `line-height: 65px` forces the children to take up 65px of space. Since this matches the parent's height, they are vertically centered.